# I'm trying to use count in this query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to solve this question using count. It's returning the right number of books for the author, but according to the question, I can't have the same book title twice. Is there a better operator to use for this question?

Here is the question:

> Find the name of the author(s) that has the largest number of different books owned by the library (multiple copies of the same book only count as one book)

Here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE Book
(
    bookID INT,
    ISBN INT,
    title varchar (30),
    author  varchar (20),
    publish_year INT,
    category varchar(20),
    PRIMARY KEY (bookID)
);  

CREATE TABLE Member
(
    memberID INT,
    lastname varchar (20),
    firstname varchar (20),
    address varchar(20),
    phone_number INT,   
    limit_ INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (memberID)
);

CREATE TABLE CurrentLoan
(
    memberID INT ,
    bookID INT,
    loan_date DATE,
    due_date DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (memberID, bookID),
    FOREIGN KEY (memberID) REFERENCES Member(memberID),
    FOREIGN KEY (bookID) REFERENCES Book(bookID)
);

CREATE TABLE History
(
    memberID INT,
    bookID INT,
    loan_date DATE,
    return_date DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (memberID, bookID, loan_date),
    FOREIGN KEY (memberID) REFERENCES Member(memberID),
    FOREIGN KEY (bookID) REFERENCES Book(bookID)
);

INSERT INTO Book 
VALUES (10, 1113312336, 'The Dog', 'Jack Crow', 1990, 'fiction');
INSERT INTO Book 
VALUES (12, 2221254896, 'Worms', 'Jim Kan', 2013, 'childrens');
INSERT INTO Book 
VALUES (13, 3332546987, 'Crow', 'Jan Flo', 2000, 'fiction'); 
INSERT INTO Book 
VALUES (14, 4443456215, 'Big Dog', 'Lan Big', 1993, 'children');
INSERT INTO Book 
VALUES (15, 5552314569, 'Green Apple', 'Theo Brown', 1978, 'children');
INSERT INTO Book 
VALUES (16, 6664581631, 'Red Bean', 'Khang Nk', 2017, 'fiction');
INSERT INTO Book 
VALUES (17, 7771452369, 'XML and XQuery', 'Author Le', 2017, 'non-fiction');
INSERT INTO Book 
VALUES (18, 8881245525, 'The Dark Room', 'Jack Se', 2017, 'fiction');
INSERT INTO Book 
VALUES (19, 9991123546, 'Yellow Bird', 'Jake Red', 2014, 'refrence');
INSERT INTO Book 
VALUES (20, 1122112356, 'XQuery: The XML Query Language', 'Heart Le', 2002, 'fiction');
INSERT INTO Book
VALUES (21, 1212121212, 'Gone Fishing', 'Shel Silverstein', 1964, 'reference');
INSERT INTO Book
VALUES (22, 2121212121, 'Gone Fishing', 'Shel Silverstein', 1964, 'reference');
INSERT INTO Book
VALUES (23, 1313131313, 'The Lazy Dog', 'Jake Red', 2016, 'children');
INSERT INTO Book
VALUES (24, 3131313131, 'The Red Bird', 'Jake Red', 2016, 'children');
INSERT INTO Book
VALUES (25, 1414141414, 'The Very Blue Boy', 'Ben Jen', 2006, 'fiction');

INSERT INTO Member 
VALUES (001, 'Lee', 'Nancy', 'Brownlea Drive', 1254896325, 10);
INSERT INTO Member 
VALUES (002, 'Le', 'Ray', '10th Street', 1234561256, 2);
INSERT INTO Member 
VALUES (003, 'Kan', 'Charlie', '5th Street', 1234567236, 8);
INSERT INTO Member 
VALUES (004, 'Brown', 'Joe', 'Elm Street', 1234567845, 9);
INSERT INTO Member 
VALUES (005, 'Smith', 'John', '33 East', 1234567890, 3);
INSERT INTO Member 
VALUES (006, 'Kope', 'NON', '358 Seng', 2145345625, 5);
INSERT INTO Member 
VALUES (007, 'Jones', 'David', '4th Street', 14812365789, 10);

INSERT INTO CurrentLoan VALUES (002, 20, '13-SEP-17', '14-NOV-17');
INSERT INTO CurrentLoan VALUES (001, 19, '13-JAN-17', '15-NOV-17');
INSERT INTO CurrentLoan VALUES (006, 17, '14-FEB-17', '12-MAR-17');
INSERT INTO CurrentLoan VALUES (003, 15, '12-OCT-17', '09-NOV-17');
INSERT INTO CurrentLoan VALUES (005, 18, '13-APR-17', '12-MAY-17');
INSERT INTO CurrentLoan VALUES (007, 25, '02-OCT-17', '25-DEC-17');

INSERT INTO History VALUES (002, 17, '14-Jan-17', '04-JUN-17');
INSERT INTO History VALUES (003, 19, '12-Jan-17', '04-NOV-17');
INSERT INTO History VALUES (001, 13, '14-APR-17', '08-OCT-17');
INSERT INTO History VALUES (006, 20, '14-MAY-17', '04-DEC-17');
INSERT INTO History VALUES (007, 12, '02-OCT-16', '25-DEC-16');
COMMIT;
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
    author, COUNT(*) AS numberofbooks
FROM 
    Book
GROUP BY 
    author 
ORDER BY 
    numberofbooks DESC;
```

Comment: so, what's the problem ?

Comment: @Ravi there's two book in BOOK that has the same title and author. Instead of having two it should be just one. I think I'm missing title in my query.

Comment: Could you post your data and expected data ?

Comment: @Ravi here is my data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3c8333/1 but for author Shel Silverstein its supposed to have just 1 not 2 since its the same title and author.

Comment: sqlfiddle isn't working for me. I have been trying for so long

Comment: Note that you're only bumping into this because this database hasn't been normalized properly: `Book` should contain exactly 1 row, and you need an extra table `Copy`, which would have one row for each individual copy, with the barcode you'd scan to check the book out.  This would also solve the problem with incorrect category data ("reference" is misspelled for one entry), although handling different editions might be tricky.  Note that there's a few other things to pull out, too, like `Author`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply use `distinct` before `title`.

```
SELECT Author, Count(distinct Title) NumberOfTitles
FROM Book
GROUP BY Author
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as your query is concerned, it is correct , please check there might be extra space in on of Authors name or spelling difference.

Answer (score 1):

To eliminate the duplicate titles, you will need to generate unique rows in a subquery, and then count those rows, like this:

```
SELECT Author, Count(*) NumberOfTitles
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Author, Title
    FROM   Book
) Subquery
GROUP BY Author
```